# OpenMDAO generating coloring files twice

Tags: openmdao

I'm wondering if this is correct. Most of the Implicit and Explicit components I have created use the line:

```
self.declare_coloring(wrt='*', method='cs', tol=1.0E-12, show_sparsity=True)
```

Then when I get to the file that runs the driver I use:

```
p.driver.declare_coloring()
```

And in my /coloring_files directory I have a 'col' and a 'disc' for each component.

```
coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_col_brakeThrottle.pkl    coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_disc_implicitOutputs.pkl
coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_col_implicitOutputs.pkl  coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_disc_powerTrain.pkl
coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_col_powerTrain.pkl       coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_disc_spin.pkl
coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_col_spin.pkl             coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_disc_timeAdder.pkl
coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_col_timeAdder.pkl        coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_disc_timeSpace.pkl
coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_col_timeSpace.pkl        coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_disc_tracking.pkl
coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_col_tracking.pkl         coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_disc_tyreConstraint.pkl
coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_col_tyreConstraint.pkl   coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_disc_tyre.pkl
coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_col_tyre.pkl             total_coloring.pkl
coloring_traj_phases_phase0_rhs_disc_brakeThrottle.pkl
```

Are both sets of files needed or am I repeating an operation twice? Also I'm wondering if declaring coloring with the driver is using a method other than CS? I do intent on using the total_coloring.pkl for static coloring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dymos can use one of two methods for transcription:  The Radau Pseudospectral Method or the high-order GaussLobatto method.

The GaussLobatto method is a two-step process:

1. The ODE is evaluated at the "discretization" nodes.
2. The values and rates at the discretization nodes are used to interpolate the state and state rates to the "collocation" nodes.
3. The ODE is evaluated a second time at the collocation nodes using the interpolated state values from step 2.
4. The interpolated rates are compared to the rates output by the ODE at the collocation nodes (these are called the defects) - if they're tiny, then the physics are assumed to be accurate.

The Radau transcription follows a similar process, except the collocation nodes are a *subset* of the discretization nodes, so interpolation isn't necessary, and the ODE only needs to be evaluated once.

If you change your transcription from `dymos.GaussLobatto` to `dymos.Radau`, then you'll only have one partial-coloring file for each of your ODE components.  Otherwise, both need to have their coloring worked out separately.

Comment: Thanks, I see their purpose now.